# numpy indexing with multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two sequences of data (of equal length) and quality values for each data point, I want to calculate a similarity score based upon a given scoring matrix.

What is the most efficient way to vectorize the following loop:

```
score = 0
for i in xrange(len(seq1)):
    score += similarity[seq1[i], seq2[i], qual1[i], qual2[i]]
```

`similarity` is a 4-dimensional float array, shape=(32, 32, 100, 100);
`seq1`, `seq2`, `qual1` and `qual2` are 1-dimensional int arrays of equal length (of the order 1000 - 40000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't this Just Work(tm)?

```
>>> score = 0
>>> for i in xrange(len(seq1)):
        score += similarity[seq1[i], seq2[i], qual1[i], qual2[i]]
...     
>>> score
498.71792400493433
>>> similarity[seq1,seq2, qual1, qual2].sum()
498.71792400493433
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

similarity = np.random.random((32, 32, 100, 100))
n = 1000
seq1, seq2, qual1, qual2 = [np.random.randint(0, s, n) for s in similarity.shape]

def slow():
    score = 0
    for i in xrange(len(seq1)):
        score += similarity[seq1[i], seq2[i], qual1[i], qual2[i]]
    return score

def fast():
    return similarity[seq1, seq2, qual1, qual2].sum()
```

gives:

```
>>> timeit slow()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.59 ms per loop
>>> timeit fast()
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 us per loop
>>> np.allclose(slow(),fast())
True
```

Comment: Well that's just great.  I like this better than my own answer (though I may leave mine just for contrast).  +1.

Comment: That's a really neat `numpy` feature I didn't know about.

Comment: Thanks! - Timings on my machine (including John Zwinck's answer as 'third') for 1000 iterations of length 10000:
slow: 17.1289219856, fast: 0.61208987236, third: 15.7027080059

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
score = numpy.sum(map(similarity.__getitem__, zip(seq1, seq2, qual1, qual2)))
```

Of course you can try with itertools imap and izip too.  The zip is necessary because `__getitem__` takes a single tuple rather than four numbers...maybe that can be improved somehow by looking in a darker corner of the itertools module.